# Hacer que de un entero me devuelva con decimales y con punto

Tags: java

Como puedo hacer para conseguir que el numero entero 55005 me salga en consola como 550.05.

Tengo esto:

```
int numero1 = (int)55005;

double numero2 =(double) numero1;

DecimalFormatSymbols separar = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
separar.setDecimalSeparator('.');

DecimalFormat formato1 = new DecimalFormat("#.00", separar);
System.out.println(formato1.format(numero2));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A priori, en tu caso la parte entera de tu  double es 55005 y por lo tanto te muestra 55005.00 como es lógico.

Tal vez sea algo tan sencillo como lo siguiente:

```
int numero1 = 55005;
double numero2 =(numero1/100.0);


DecimalFormatSymbols separar = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
separar.setDecimalSeparator('.');

DecimalFormat formato1 = new DecimalFormat("#.00", separar);
System.out.println(formato1.format(numero2));
```

Comment: buah, muchas gracias. Me estaba liando al final lo he conseguido pero mucho mas largo.